'could not determine data type of parameter' when sending text to PostgreSQL db
I am trying to send a JSON as text to a postgis / PostgreSQL function with pg in node / typescript.
I do this by:
            const excludeGeojson = {
                "coordinates": [
                  [
                    [
                      13.052800998359942,
                      52.40228431090625
                    ],
                    [
                      13.048063265289755,
                      52.397217941608375
                    ],
                    [
                      13.060780338266397,
                      52.398328636914954
                    ],
                    [
                      13.052800998359942,
                      52.40228431090625
                    ]
                  ]
                ],
                "type": "Polygon"
              }
    

            const query = sql`SELECT query_cityjson_excludetest(${z},${x},${y},'${JSON.stringify(excludeGeojson)}')
            `.execute()

which results in this error message:
PostgresError: could not determine data type of parameter $4
    at ErrorResponse (/home/user/git/tilesDB/node_modules/postgres/cjs/src/connection.js:788:26)
    at handle (/home/user/git/tilesDB/node_modules/postgres/cjs/src/connection.js:474:6)
    at Socket.data (/home/user/git/tilesDB/node_modules/postgres/cjs/src/connection.js:315:9)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:519:28)
    at Socket.emit (node:domain:488:12)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:559:12)
    at readableAddChunkPushByteMode (node:internal/streams/readable:510:3)
    at Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:390:5)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:191:23)
    at cachedError (/home/user/git/tilesDB/node_modules/postgres/cjs/src/query.js:170:23)
    at new Query (/home/user/git/tilesDB/node_modules/postgres/cjs/src/query.js:36:24)
    at sql (/home/user/git/tilesDB/node_modules/postgres/cjs/src/index.js:112:11)
    at /home/user/git/tilesDB/src/app.ts:112:30 {
  severity_local: 'ERROR',
  severity: 'ERROR',
  code: '42P18',
  file: 'postgres.c',
  line: '736',
  routine: 'pg_analyze_and_rewrite_varparams'
}

if I run the query directly it works:
SELECT query_cityjson_excludetest(17,70293,43054,'{"coordinates":[[[13.052800998359942,52.40228431090625],[13.048063265289755,52.397217941608375],[13.060780338266397,52.398328636914954],[13.052800998359942,52.40228431090625]]],"type":"Polygon"}')

what is wrong here?
Thanks a lot for help!

try using " before every " (quotation).

@manjunath Not sure I understand how that would help here.

@DaveNewton I thought direct usage of  " (quotation) causes problem when converting excludeGeojson to text.To include " in text format should'nt we use " rather than " ?

Problem could be that when executing query directly postgres can pick up the json type, that might not be the case when building query in code. To be sure you can cast the expression to ::jsonb.
'${JSON.stringify(excludeGeojson)}::jsonb'

sql.unsafe() does the trick :/
```const query = sql.unsafe(SELECT ${functionName}('${JSON.stringify(excludeGeojson)}'::text,${z},${x},${y})).execute()


@manjunath You need to escape quotes if they're in a string delimited w/ the same quote, otherwise it should just be a string quote. If something in geojson breaks string parsing like that it'd be a bug IMO.
